# How to implement both table view and scroll view in a window through storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, single-page-application

I have a single view application. I want to add a table view that will cover whole window. After select a row, Table view will be disappear & scroll view will appear with some label, button, text field etc.

The scroll view will cover whole window also. What will be the best way to do it ?

Is it possible in storyboard ?

I am new in iOS development. Please point me in the right direction if so.

Thanks.

Comment: Use UINavigationController with rootViewController has tableView and on cell selection push new ViewController which has scrollView as user can go back to tableView's ViewController

Comment: Yes it is possible with storyBoard. both view (ScrollView and UITableView)  are design as per your requirement but hide scrollView in ViewDidLoad.when you click on tableViewCell  hide your UITableView and unhide your scrollView.

Comment: Then should i drag and drop scroll view over table view or vice versa from object library in storyboard and connect outlet reference of both in view controller where i can hide/unhide of either one ?